# Visual Studio Code update include path

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-code, include-path

This is my code. But it is showing to update include path,I don't know how to.

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
std::cout << "test this!";
return 0;
```

Comment: Which operating system are you using? Also, the code is faulty – missing closing braces.

Comment: How you build that code? Could you please show more details?

Answer (score 0):

1. If your compiler is VScode, I suggest you could perform the following operations.

1.1 Press "Shift+Ctrl+p" Input: C++Configurations, select UI interface.

1.2 Just add the path of the header file you need in the include path.

1.3 If you don not know, you could enter commands on the command line:

```
gcc -v -E -x c++ -
```

Then, copy and paste the obtained results into the include path

[image]

2. If your compiler is Visual Studio, you could add the include path in `Properties->VC++ Directories->Include Directories`.